# django-tailwind is not rebuilding styles

Tags: python, node.js, django, django-tailwind

I'm trying to use tailwind with my django project and i've followed as this documentation
(https://django-tailwind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) when i'm making changes in tailwind classes in my html files in the terminal it get rebuild but the changes are not being seen to my design somehow.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'authen',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tailwind',
    'theme',
    'django_browser_reload',
    'rental',
    'roommate'
]
TAILWIND_APP_NAME = 'theme'
INTERNAL_IPS = [
    "127.0.0.1",
]
```

index.html in my templates folder where theme, manage.py etc folders exist.

```
{% load static tailwind_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rentopia</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/home.png' %}" type="image/png">
     {% tailwind_css %}
```

i've tried with this in package.json but it still does nothing

```
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=1 tailwindcss --postcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ../static/css/dist/styles.css -w",
```

Comment: did you Install Tailwind CSS dependencies ? with `python manage.py tailwind install` as well as the middlware  `django_browser_reload.middleware.BrowserReloadMiddleware`

Comment: yes i did. its an old project so everything was working fine. after few month i've started working on it again. now i see this problem. but all the taliwind classes that i wrote before works fine suppose if i use bg-black it works because its been used before but new one does not

Comment: @monim if anything needed to be added please ask

Comment: what is your **django-tailwind** version

Comment: django-tailwind==3.5.0

Comment: i have tried to add this in tailwind config file but doesn't work ```mode: "jit",```

Comment: well i guss you were working with v2 and moved to v3 .follow the instruction [here](https://django-tailwind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrade.html) to make it work